# How to change the order of <div> in mobile?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I use the style that I mention below and as you see I have a sticky sidebar in desktop.

```css
.sidebar-item {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.make-me-sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 130px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <img src="https://spanishclub.ie/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Blazquez-admi-2-min-600x600.jpg" class="img-fluid">
    <div class="pt-5">
      <h2>The information about product</h2>
      <p>The xtra information about product</p>
      <div class="accordion bb2" id="accordion">
    <div class="card" style="border: 0px solid; border-radius: 0rem ; border-top: 2px solid #ccc; border-button: 2px solid #ccc; ">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button class=" ml-n3 text-dark btn btn-link collapsed w-100 text-left text-decoration-none" style="font-weight: 600; font-size: 1.27rem; " data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                    Product Overview 
                </button>
            </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse bg-light show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="card-body  mt-n4 mb-n2" style="font-weight: 400;  font-size: 15px; ">
                <p>lIn publishing and graphic design, Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document or a typeface without relying on meaningful content. Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
  <div class="clearfix"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5 ">
    <div class="sidebar-item">
      <div class="make-me-sticky">
        <h2>Title of product</h2>
        <button class="btn"> Add to basket</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there any solution to change the order in mobile? The order I imagine seeing in  mobile:

- first row: picture
- second row: price and title
- third row: the information

Comment: If you use `display: flex` then you might use `order` on its direct child elements See for an example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

Comment: Thanks @bron , In fact, I am looking for a solution to move `col-md-5` in  to `col-md-7` exactly below `img` only in mobile.

Comment: There is the `order` property in CSS. Not ideal for a11y. Else re-draw your dom

Comment: Thanks @JonathanHamel , It is important for me to have a sticky sidebar.